# Title back button onCreate

Tags: android, back, titlebar

My app starts with the MainActivity, which is nothing but a simple menu with buttons for sub menus:

**Start**

**Options**

**Help**

**etc...**

Each sub menu option starts a new activity.
These new activities (submenus) will have a **Back button on the top in the Title bar**.

When I press these **back button on the top**, it goes back to the Main Menu activity as expected, but it calls onCreate function of the Main Activity.
This is not good, it equals to an app restart in my case.

If I press the **physical back button** and I implement the onBackPressed function,
it can resume to the Main Menu without calling the onCreate function,
which is my desired behaviour.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

How can I force the **Title bar Back button** not to call the **onCreate** function of the caller activity?
Is there any other function I have to override to make it not happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the **Up** button the parent activity is called. Sort of like a `startActivity` call, which creates a new instance of the chosen activity.

To prevent that, you can specify that only a single instance of your Start activity can be created. Set this in your manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: I have this singleInstance setting, but does not solve my case. I am talking about the Title bar soft back button.

Comment: Ops, my mistake, it actually helped to make all of my activities, single instanced. I am not sure about the consequences, but its working now. Thanks user3249477